# jQuery animation works OK on JSfiddle, but does not on Wordpress (localhost Apache)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I try to run a jquery script, which works OK on jsfiddle, but when I move it to Wordpress it does not. I replaced "$" with "jquery" already, as I know the WP won't process $s.

The jsFiddle shows exactly how it suppose to act. After migrating this to WP, nothing happens on click. Do you have any ideas what can cause the issue?

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/7e9pfd6L/23/)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.footbtn').click(function() {
    if (jQuery('.slideupmenu').hasClass('menuup')) {
      jQuery('.slideupmenu').addClass('menudown', 100, 'linear');
      jQuery('.slideupmenu').removeClass('menuup');
    } else {
      jQuery('.slideupmenu').removeClass('menudown');
      jQuery('.slideupmenu').addClass('menuup', 100, 'linear');
    }
  });

  jQuery('.x').click(function() {
    jQuery('.slideupmenu').addClass('menudown', 100, 'linear');
    jQuery('.slideupmenu').removeClass('menuup');
  });
});
```

```css
.footbtn {
  z-index: 1000!important;
  padding: 30px;
  background: green;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.slideupmenu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  bottom: -100%;
  z-index: 900!important;
}

.x {
  padding: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}

.menuup {
  bottom: 0px !important;
}

.menudown {
  bottom: -100% !important;
}

body {
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="footbtn">
    CLICK
    </a>

<div class="slideupmenu">
  <div class="x">
    X
  </div>

  <br />
  <br /> Line 1<br /> Line 2<br /> Line 3<br /> Line 4
</div>
```

I am struggling with this for a few hours now and just gave up.
I also added local jquery file instead of the generic WP jquery. Still no joy. All libraries are loaded before the above code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Open the console and check for errors. The problem is most likely that you haven't included jquery.js in the page properly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, The console shows some minor issues with bootstrap (missing map files), but not anything related to this issue. It seems that everything was loaded properly

Comment: If that was the case then your code would be working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, unfortunately still no joy :( I guess this is something small and stupid, but the website itself is quite large already. There are no other jquery scripts which can interfere... weird stuff

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your WP plugins and using the default WP theme (without Bootstrap) with your code?

Comment: Perhaps try a delegated event handler if the content is dynamically loaded, eg. `jQuery(document).on('click', '.footbtn', function() {`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan still nothing. I replaced the line with yours and still no joy. I believe this is too wide issue to address it precisely.

Comment: @j08691, removed bootstrap libraries and disabled plugins... still nothing

Comment: I found the issue - apparently this code was causing it (weird) - <?php wp_footer();?>

And Bootstrap  :( 
Now I have a problem, as I need bootstrap for this website. Somethint is not right here..

Comment: I figured it out. Works OK now. Had to add !important to slideupmenu class next to display:block